# FocusOut vs Click

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня на форме есть ввод города

```
<div class="windowItem" id="city_match" style="display: none">
    <div class="windowItem__title">Введите название города</div>
    <input type="text" value="" name="CITY" />
    <div class="windowItem__resultBlock" style="display: none">
        <div class="windowItem__cityItems">
            <div class="windowItem__cityItem">Минск</div>
            <div class="windowItem__cityItem">Гомель</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="windowItem__errorMsg">Город не найден</div>
</div>
```

И обработчики. При `keyup` показывается блок подсказок под инпутом (там еще будет через запрос загружаться список городов потом), при `focusout` он скрывается, а вот при `click` должна выбранная подсказка копироваться в инпут и скрывать блок подсказок, но почему-то событие клика не вызывается... Такое ощущение что потеря фокуса его перебивает. Почему так? =(

```
$('form#add_address #city_match input').keyup(e => {
    $('form#add_address #city_match .windowItem__resultBlock').show();
});

$('form#add_address #city_match input').focusout(e => {
    $('form#add_address #city_match .windowItem__resultBlock').hide();
});

$('form#add_address #city_match .windowItem__cityItem').click(e => {
    $('form#add_address #city_match input').val(e.target.textContent);
    $('form#add_address #city_match .windowItem__resultBlock').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

здесь:

```
$('form#add_address #city_match input').focusout(e => {
   $('form#add_address #city_match .windowItem__resultBlock').hide();
});
```

заменить hide на fadeOut.
возможно вам нужен datalist:
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist

Comment: Хмм, но мне надо чтобы он был скрыт по умолчанию... Там он потом показывается по другому событию

Comment: Ого, первый раз слышу про такой элемент)))

Comment: И все таки, как победить мою проблему? Я пытался вешать обработчик через `$('form#add_address #city_match').on('click', '.windowItem__cityItem', e => ...`, но тоже не выходит, а ведь (я кстати только что прочитал) такой способ должен работать даже с динамически добавляемыми элементами.

Comment: И кто вообще вам сказал что скрытые элементы не ловят события? Я такое первый раз слышу... Почему же тогда другие события работают? С `keyup` и `focusout` все норм, хотя изначально они тоже скрыты.

Comment: @ПЭХАПЭШНИК https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272360/does-opacity0-have-exactly-the-same-effect-as-visibilityhidden/273076#273076

Comment: Но почему тогда другие события работают???

Comment: Даже когда я внес навешивание обработчиков `focusout` и `click` в событие `keyup` (после вызова `show` на блоке подсказок) ничего не изменилось

Comment: @ПЭХАПЭШНИК, <div class="windowItem" id="city_match" style="display: none"> это первая строка вашего кода. display:none при каком условии убирается?

Comment: Там перед этим `select` городов. Если выбран пункт "другой" то показывается поле для ручного ввода города. С этим все нормально - оно работает.

Comment: @ПЭХАПЭШНИК отредактировал

Comment: О! Помогло, спасибо!